# Why an element x below to another element y moved up when element y has an absolute position

Tags: css, html, css-position

There is a div `container` which contains 2 boxes Yellow and Green. 
Green box is just below the yellow box. When we move yellow box using top and bottom relative to the container then it moves without disturbing the position of green box.
But when we move Yellow box using top and bottom `Absolutely` to the container then Green box also moves up. Why green box's position got changed?

[JSFiddle Output](https://jsfiddle.net/avinashkharche/krtxa8p2/8/)

```css
.box {
      width:100px;
      height:100px; 
    }
    
    .container {
      width:500px;
      height:500px; 
      position:relative;
      background: #333;
    }

    #box-1 {
      position: relative;
      top: 50px;
      left:50px;
      background: red;
    }
    #box-2 {
      position: absolute;
      /* position: relative; */
      top:100px;
      left:100px;
      background: yellow;
    }
    #box-3 {
      background: green;
    }
    #box-4 {
      background: blue;
    }
    #box-5 {
      background: orange;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <style>
    
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="box-1" class="box"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="box-2" class="box"></div>
    <div id="box-3" class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="box-4" class="box"></div>
  <div id="box-5" class="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `absolute:
The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout` (again about *space*)

Answer (score 0):

You'll find your answer here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

However, the computed position of an element when it is absolutely positioned are specific offsets from the edges of the parent or the element to which this one is positioned. It doesn't follow the rules of the other elements, is like if you stuck it out from the flow of the other elements.

On the other hand, a relatively positioned object is the most confusing. It means 'relative to itself', but its position is influenced by other elements in the flow.

So, the Green box is actually moving because you are removing the Yellow one from the 'landscape'.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

**RELATIVE positioned element** is positioned `relative to ITSELF`.

Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.

```
This <div> element has position: relative;
```

An **ABSOLUTE positioned** element is positioned relative to IT'S `CLOSEST POSITIONED PARENT.` if one is present, then it works like fixed.....relative to the window.

However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling.

for further understanding you may visit 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp